# Restrict TFS access to certain IP only

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to restrict access to a Team Foundation Server 2010 to a certain IP addresses only? I don't want to block access from outside but allow people to connect from certain locations only.

Comment: This should be the job of the firewall

Comment: Or IPSec - eg http://codehill.com/2010/02/how-to-block-ip-addresses-in-windows-server-2003/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution was to edit the allowed and blocked IP address from the TFS website in IIS